# Angular change text based on variable

Tags: angularjs

I'm hiding or showing a div when a button is clicked.

I want to change the text in the link to say "show" / "hide".

I have it working but is there a better way to change the text rather than checking for the variable on two seprate spans.

```
    <a ng-click="showHint = !showHint"><span ng-if="showHint">Hide</span><span ng-if="!showHint">Show</span> tips</a>

    <div ng-if="showHint">
        <p>
            Hint text Hint text Hint text Hint text 
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this, hope it works for you:

```
<span ng-bind="showHint ? 'Hide' : 'Show'"></span>
```

Complete Snippet:

```
<a ng-click="showHint = !showHint">
    <span ng-bind="showHint ? 'Hide' : 'Show'"></span> tips
</a>
```

OR

```
<a ng-click="showHint = !showHint">
    <span ng-bind="showHint ? 'Hide tips' : 'Show tips'"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use conditional operator with interpolation.

```
<a ng-click="showHint = !showHint">{{ showHint ? "Hide" : "Show"}}tips</a>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/6647ftnb/)